# Firefox div parent width head-ache

Tags: css, firefox, drupal-7, html

I am making a site. I am using Drupal 7 with HTML5 strater kit of Omega theme. I have poped up two regions. Each one contains an image and some text (image on the top and text in the bottom). Now the display for the IE9 and chrome is OK but for firefox is not understandable for my brain. the address is http://cakes.apakistanichristian.co.uk/. the reason i am giving out the web address is because i have no idea what css or html code i should post. Just open it in firefox, IE and chrome you will see the difference. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to work as the same form Chrome and Firefox

Comment: thanks for looking at it, though i have clear cache of firefox22 but it was showing me different result to IE and Chrome. Perhaps i should restart the firefox and try it. May i know are you using windows or Linux?

Comment: I'm using Linux (Mint 14 KDE)

Comment: i am using window8 with firefox 22. i just checked after restarting firefox, clearing the cache of drupal and firefox and result is same. It is showing long column of the text rather then contained into the parent div.

Comment: Perhaps it's better to decide first if the page should be HTML or XHTML. Then rewrite the page so that it's valid HTML or valid XHTML. The W3C validator is very confused by your current approach.

Comment: all the code is produced by drupal 7 and omega HTML5 starter kit.